# PHP script doesn't reroute to thankyou page

Tags: php, forms

I have a form which submits and /should/ reroute to a thankyou.html page.

Below is the script I'm using:

```
<?php
  $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

  mail( "myemail@gmail.com", "Feedback Form Results",
    $message, "From: $email" );
  header( "thankyou.html" );
?>
```

The thankyou page definitely exists and works correctly, is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. `header` sets an HTTP header, it doesn't redirect. You can, however, use it to redirect to a page by setting the [*Location*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) header.

```
header("Location: thankyou.html");
```

A note about relative URLs when using the *Location* header:

> This example, is incorrect according to the standard, which specifies the URI returned to be absolute. However, most popular browsers will accept a relative URL.

Comment: +1 for beating me by 3 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. Is there perhaps a better way to do this? Or is this fine?

Comment: Always use the full path

Comment: Thanks, will do. Any reasons why? I'm just learning PHP so I'd appreciate explanations on these things so I know why I'm doing certain things :)

Comment: "Note:

HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself: " -Thus spoke the manual

Comment: @FrancescaHaselden see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location Basically, it's not supposed to work with relative URLs, but most browsers will accept it anyways

Comment: Who here uses the HTML5 doctype header? Yeah, that's not actually a standard. Who cares. Relative URLs will always work.

Comment: @Rudie i always use the correct doctype header, just because you are lazy, don't suggest others follow suite.

Comment: Correct? Which one is correct? Lazy has nothing to do with it. If we'd all use standards only and not new things, we'd stil be in 1998. Anyway, I'm not having this discussion.

Comment: @Rudie In what sense is it not a standard? I'm really interested. Relative URLs will always work, unless you change something and never recognize what caused the bugs. Standards are there for a reason - not to restrict, but to help.

Comment: HTML5 doctype is a working draft. Doesn't matter because it's worked forever. Same for  (relative) paths in a Location header. Rudie out.

Answer (score 3):

`header` sets HTTP headers.  There is a specific header called `Location` that can redirect.

You want:

```
header('Location: thankyou.html');
```